# How to replace a value in one temporary column depending on another column mysql using SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Hi so basically this is the table where the newField is just a temporary field that shows up when retrieving it. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqIA2.png)

However what I need to is when I select the table and let's say the mark is greater than 50, the corresponding value under the newField column should be "B" then when greater than 78 should be "A-" and so on...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CASE WHEN` clause to achieve this

```
SELECT *, 
    CASE 
        WHEN mark > 50 THEN "A"
        WHEN mark <= 50 THEN "B"
    END AS newField
FROM your_table
```

Comment: Hi I did try that already but for some reason I keep getting an error and I believe it could be a syntax issue? 

This was my code block: 

SELECT id, name, marks, 'grade' as newField 
    CASE
        WHEN marks >= 50 THEN "PASS"
        WHEN marks < 50 THEN "FAIL"
    END AS newField
FROM students;

According to the terminal this part is where the error at:
CASE
        WHEN marks >= 50 THEN "PASS"
        WHEN marks < 50 THEN "FAIL"
END AS newField

I tried writing it one line but same error persists.

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE
        WHEN marks >= 50 THEN "PASS"
        WHEN marks < 50 THEN "FAIL"...' at line 2

Comment: remove 'grade' as, I have AS newField at the end, only one alias should be defined.

Comment: Yup I already did but somehow it's still giving me an error, but I was able to fix it! I forgot to put a comma after selecting which column names I want to retrieve or after the asterisk.